# Track social media referrer url through Mobile app

Tags: javascript, android, ios, social-media

Is there something in order to track `document.referrer` if user comes from social media **mobile application** like Facebook,twitter...etc

Basically I want to track `document.referrer` when user click on particular link in both cases Websites and Mobile Apps

Also looking for track `document.referrer` when facebook and other social media Mobile apps open link in `inner web view`  of Mobile application.